# How to remove the 2nd and 3rd page header and footers In TOC?

Tags: table-of-contents, header-footer, books

Hi guys I am trying to create the from my project report using **book document class**.
I am facing one problem regarding toc. I have 4 pages in toc .but In the second and third page have the header and footer.(1st and 4th page do not have the header and footer)  I tried and I search regarding this topic but I didn't get so please help me  to remove the header and footer.
here i this tried code

```
\makeatletter\@openrightfalse
%----- Table of content--------------
\tableofcontents{\thispagestyle{empty}}
\cleardoublepage
\@openrighttrue\makeatother
```

Comment: Could you add a minimal working example in your question so as to understand your issue better?

Comment: The answer should give the result you want, but it doesn't say why.  Here's why.  `\tableofcontents` doesn't take any arguments, so the table of contents has actually been processed by the time you request `\thispagestyle{empty}`.  So that takes effect only on the last contents page.

Comment: @barbarabeeton Further, `\thispagestyle{...}` only applies to the current page. The questioner said that there were 4 pages in the ToC so the `\thispagestyle` would only effect one of the 4 pages.

Comment: Thank u guys i found it 

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Something along the lines:

```
...
\pagestyle{empty}
\tableofcontents
\cleardoublepage
% reset the pagestyle
```

Comment: Thank u guys i found it 